# Control scientific notation and format of zero values with knitr and tables produced with kable()

Tags: r, knitr, scientific-notation

I have a small table that I am displaying in a pdf document generated by knitr in Rstudio.

Most of the values are small numbers, so scientific notation is fine. However, I have a few zeros that also get displayed in scientific notation.

Is there a way to show these as just regular zeros?

Here is an image:

[image: basic table with scientific notation for zeros]

The table was produced with `kable(data)`

Comment: You could try  `options(scipen=999)` before issuing your `kable(data)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. The general idea is that you first format the numbers the way you want (number of decimal places, etc.), then change ones that are zero to "0".

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
date: "August 17, 2016"
output:
  pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
```

```{r}
# Some data
df = mtcars[1:5,c(1,3:4)]/1e7
rownames(df) = NULL

# Set a few values to zero
df[2:3,2] = 0
df[c(1,3),1] = 0

# Look at the starting data
kable(df)
```

```{r}
## Reformat table so that zeros are rendered as "0"

# First, format data so that every number is rendered with two decimal places
df = lapply(df, format, digits=3)

# If a value is zero, change string representation to "0" instead of "0.00e+00"
df = sapply(df, function(i) ifelse(as.numeric(i) == 0, "0", i))

kable(df, align=rep('r',3))
```
````

[image]